# Return first part of filename and not the file extension

Tags: php, file

I have a file: ./image/photo.jpg

I was wondering if there is a php function that returns just the filename without the extension without the use of regular expression.

I have used some functions but it returns photo.jpg

Comment: what function you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$string = './image/photo.jpg';
echo pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // output: photo
```

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.basename.php

```
<?php
$string = './image/photo.jpg';
$name = basename($string, '.jpg');
// $name will now contain "photo"
```

or http://php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php

```
<?php
$string = './image/photo.jpg';
$info = pathinfo($string);
// $info['filename'] will now contain "photo"
```

Comment: the problem here is, when the extension is .jpeg or something other... ok, with pathinfo, that's working